# Updating current user data with different tables using parse.com and Android

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am working on parse.com and updating current user data. I just want to update the current user information in another data for example "UserInfo" table, in which I want to put some updated values.

Code snippet for current user is given below:

```
ParseUser user = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
user.put("firstName", fName.getText().toString());
user.put("lastName", lName.getText().toString());
user.put("email", mailText.getText().toString());
user.put("contactNumber", mobileText.getText().toString());
/*user.put("dob", medCond.getText().toString());
user.put("lastName", medication.getText().toString());
user.put("lastName", docInfo.getText().toString());*/
user.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
    @Override
    public void done(ParseException e) {
        //  dismissLoadingDialog();
        if (e == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "User Profile Has Been Updated!",
                           Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Logs.e(getClass().getName(), e.toString());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Exception/n"+e,
                           Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //  howMessage(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
});
```

But I want to update few values in my another table also. The following code is making every new entry in data bases. I want to make only an update not creation of new row.

```
final ParseObject update = new ParseObject("UserInfo");

update.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
    @Override
    public void done(ParseException arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        update.put("blood", spinnerOsversions.getSelectedItem().toString());
        update.put("doc", "");
        update.put("medicate", "ldldm");
        update.put("medical", "cdlmldm");
        update.put("medicalCond", "lalalla");
        update.put("allergy", "Twice A Day");
        update.saveInBackground();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not very familiar with Parse but I imagine if you add the userId as a primary key to the UserInfo table, when trying to save, it should update that tuple instead of creating a new one due to the primary key constraint.

Answer (score 1):

Before you can update you need to retrieve the object first. Either by objectId or another query:

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("GameScore");

// Retrieve the object by id
query.getInBackground("xWMyZ4YEGZ", new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
  public void done(ParseObject gameScore, ParseException e) {
    if (e == null) {
      // Now let's update it with some new data. In this case, only cheatMode and score
      // will get sent to the Parse Cloud. playerName hasn't changed.
      gameScore.put("score", 1338);
      gameScore.put("cheatMode", true);
      gameScore.saveInBackground();
    }
  }
});
```

[Parse.com documentation](https://parse.com/docs/android_guide#objects-updating)